# Bash script to update path to ssl certificate file in ssl.conf

Tags: bash, apache, shell, ssl

I am creating a reusable script for automating the setup of new SSLs on server setups. I have a few different lines that need to get the file paths updated.

The defaults in the ssl.conf file look like this (One has leading # tag):

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
```

I need it to be dynamically set in the bash script, to end up like this:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.crt
```

So far I started out with this, but i'm not sure what I'm doing.

```
~/update_ssl_conf.sh
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
SSL_CONFIG_PATH="/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf"

SSL_DEFAULT_CERT_PATH="SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt"
SSL_CERT_PATH="SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.crt"
sed "s/.*\b$SSL_DEFAULT_CERT_PATH\b.*/$SSL_CERT_PATH/" $SSL_CONFIG_PATH
```

***UPDATED AREA, Also need sed command to update lines that begin with #.

The defaults in the ssl.conf file look like this (Has leading # tag):

```
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I need it to be dynamically set in the bash script, to end up like this:

```
 SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example-ca-bundle.crt
```

So far I started out with this, but i'm not sure what I'm doing.

```
~/update_ssl_conf.sh
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
SSL_CONFIG_PATH="/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf"

SSL_DEFAULT_CA_CERT_PATH="#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt" 
SSL_CA_CERT_PATH="SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example-ca-bundle.crt"
```

I tried from the accepted solution for the

```
sed -i "s|.*\b#$SSL_DEFAULT_CA_CERT_PATH\b.*|$SSL_CA_CERT_PATH|" SSL_CONFIG_PATH
```

and

```
sed -i "s|(?s).*(?<!\\w)$SSL_DEFAULT_CA_CERT_PATH(?!\\w).*|$SSL_CA_‌​CERT_PATH|" $SSL_CONFIG_PATH
```

neither are working because the regular expression is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with slashes. Your variable contains them and the final command will have multiple forward slashes, which affect your original `sed` syntax of s/`<search>/<replace/` syntax. Just change your `sed` word separator from `/` to `|` (or any other character e.g say `@` or `~`) to fix it.

```
sed -i "s|.*\b$SSL_DEFAULT_CERT_PATH\b.*|$SSL_CERT_PATH|" file
```

should solve your problem and use the `-i` flag to do in-place substitution and do `-i.bak` to save a backup of the file in the format `<filename>.bak`

The `GNU sed`, `man` page says

> The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command.
>   The / character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a \ character.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. When I run with -v I see it correctly updates it. The only thing is it is not saving the file. Is this s permissions issue or do I need to add another command to save the change?

Comment: @zeros-and-ones: Refer my update, use the `-i` flag.

Comment: @zeros-and-ones: That is just to create a back-up of the original file, in case something screws up your original file i.e. may be an incorrect substitution.

Comment: Its making me wait 1 minute more...Thanks a lot saved me so much time!

Comment: @zeros-and-ones: Happy to help!

Comment: For a bonus do you know how to word match this? (Begins with #) ```SSL_DEFAULT_CA_CERT_PATH="#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
SSL_CA_CERT_PATH="SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/$APP_FOLDER_NAMEcabundle.crt"```

Comment: I have this, but its not working yet: ```sed -i "s|(?s).*(?<!\\w)$SSL_DEFAULT_CA_CERT_PATH(?!\\w).*|$SSL_CA_CERT_PATH|" $SSL_CONFIG_PATH```

Comment: @zeros-and-ones: It is generally not recommended to ask another question as part of an older question. But however, I can help you for once? Can you update the question with the actual search and replacement parts, it is not quite clear here.

Comment: @zeros-and-ones : couldn't find time today. I can spend time on it tomorrow or you can ask a new question quickly for others to respond. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I added it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861469/bash-script-to-update-path-to-ssl-certificate-file-in-ssl-conf-regex-word-match Thanks for update!