# Bash script to update path to SSL certificate file in ssl.conf (RegEx word match with #)

Tags: regex, bash, apache, ssl, sed

I am creating a reusable script for automating the setup of new SSLs on server setups. I have a few different lines that need to get the file paths updated.

The defaults in the ssl.conf file look like this (Has leading # tag):

```
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I need it to be dynamically set in the bash script, to end up like this:

```
 SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example-ca-bundle.crt
```

So far I started out with this, but i'm not sure what I'm doing.

```
~/update_ssl_conf.sh
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
SSL_CONFIG_PATH="/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf"

SSL_DEFAULT_CA_CERT_PATH="#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt" 
SSL_CA_CERT_PATH="SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example-ca-bundle.crt"
```

I tried starting with the accepted solution linked below, and adding in a # after \b.

[Bash script to update path to ssl certificate file in ssl.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837615/bash-script-to-update-path-to-ssl-certificate-file-in-ssl-conf/41837742?noredirect=1#comment70906306_41837742)

```
sed -i "s|.*\b#$SSL_DEFAULT_CA_CERT_PATH\b.*|$SSL_CA_CERT_PATH|" SSL_CONFIG_PATH
```

and

```
sed -i "s|(?s).*(?<!\\w)$SSL_DEFAULT_CA_CERT_PATH(?!\\w).*|$SSL_CA_‌​CERT_PATH|" $SSL_CONFIG_PATH
```

I have a feeling neither are working because the regular expression is not 100% correct.

Comment: I haven't looked at this in detail, but I notice a couple of things right off the bat. The leading "#" in .conf files is put there to comment out that line. It's like "//" in C. It shouldn't be included if you are actually using that line. Also, it appears to me that the statements to set the PATH have a file name at the end of them. The PATH should not include any file name, just the path to it.

Comment: Yea I understand its just commenting it out, but I was going to do a regular expression match on the whole line, then replace the whole line with it uncommented and the actual file in use substituted in for the default. I thought this would be less steps than finding the correct line, removing the #, then changing the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groups with `()` to match group of expressions :

```
SSL_CONFIG_PATH=/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

SSL_CA_CERT_PATH=/etc/pki/tls/certs/example-ca-bundle.crt

sed -ri "s|(.*#)(SSLCACertificateFile)\s+(.*)|\2 $SSL_CA_CERT_PATH|" $SSL_CONFIG_PATH
```

- `(.*#)` match the comment
- `(SSLCACertificateFile)` match the field name
- `(.*)` match the value

Only the field name (group 2 `\2`) is required following by your new path

Comment: Thank you this works, I am guessing the -r flag is for the groups in RegEx?

Comment: SSLCertificateFile happens twice, so I want to get the one that starts on a newline. ```sed -ri "s|(^)(SSLCertificateFile)\s+(.*)|\2 $SSL_CERT_PATH|" $SSL_CONFIG_PATH``` I think that is correct, it worked.

Comment: `-r` is for using Extended Regular Expressions, [see this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4a)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I like his site title.